# SwfObject registerObject?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, swfobject

I usually used embed for flash files, but I'm interested in using SwfObject.
The question is, do I have to write this on the head of my web page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.registerObject("myId", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
</script>
```

Or could I simply use this:

```
        <object id="myId" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="300" height="120">
            <param name="movie" value="test.swf" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="test.swf" width="300" height="120">
            <!--<![endif]-->
            <div>
                <h1>Alternative content</h1>
                <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
            </div>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
```

Another question, what does the classid mean? do I have to provide this value?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`swfobject.registerSWF` is only required in two use cases:

1. If you want to use Express Install
2. If you want to require the user to have a minimum version of Flash Player before trying to view your SWF.

If neither of these cases apply to you, you can simply put the `<object>` element in your markup as you have written above.

If you decide to take advantage of `swfobject.registerSWF`, it should be placed in the `<head>` of your document, after importing the SWFObject JavaScript file. See the examples in the [official documentation](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) or at [learnswfobject.com](http://learnswfobject.com/).

Regarding classid, it's for Internet Explorer. The outer `<object>` is for IE while the inner `<object>` is for pretty much every other browser. They require sightly different syntax. The classid value never changes. If you don't want to worry about it, use a SWFObject markup generator to generate the code for you: http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/generator/index.html or http://learnswfobject.com/generator/

Answer (score 0):

To your first question: No!. You have to write after the html element `<object id="myId"></object>` is rendered, because this javascript will be executed at first sight.

To second question: This is an entry in the registry, where some informations about the swf plugin can be found. You need that for InternetExplorer and similar under Windows.

Comment: I downloaded the swfobject zip file from google code, and they provided an example file with the registerObject on the head section, before the myId was declared, anyway, do I have to use this line of code? or can I just skip it and use the object element without it?

Comment: And how do I know what classid I need to use?

Comment: @1rst comment: the author of SWFobjects provides to ways: the static way, there an object tag does exists in the page and a "dynamic way". If you choose the last one, the js library will do all nessecary things for you. @ 2nd comment: the classid is fix.

Comment: btw. I have to correct my answer at first point. After including the js library you can also define it the init line in the head section.

Comment: This is incorrect.  SWFObject expects registerSWF to be in the document head. See the documentation. http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation#STEP_3:_Register_your_Flash_content_with_the_SWFObject_library_a

Comment: Expanding on my previous comment: we have seen many people report unexpected behavior when placing registerSWF in the document's body. It was designed to be placed in the document's head, placing it anywhere else can lead to problems.

Comment: Noted, sorry for any offense. But my response still stands: don't place it in the body, it can lead to unexpected problems.